# How to Implement YUI Compresser in a website

Tags: php, javascript, css, apache, yui

I wish to create a js/css minifying website using yahoo YUI compressor. How can I use this on my webserver. My server is running apache. How to run this jar files in my server. What should I do for that? I wish to create the side in PHP along with YUI?

I found this on the web. will it help me?
    https://github.com/gpbmike/PHP-YUI-Compressor

Comment: You want to make a general purpose minifier service for everyone to use? Or just auto-min some of your own JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at https://github.com/mrclay/minify, 
while it includes a wrapper for the YUI compressor (which itself is a java command line tool) 
it's also a standalone PHP library.

http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/UserGuide